# Not able to connect to RTC repository using maven mvn scm:status

Tags: maven-2

```
I want to connect with RTC repository workspace, I have used following scm tag in my pom.xml

<scm>  <connection>scm:jazz:username;password@https://jtsrv.him:9091/jazz:My Repository Workspaces/Log-MainStream</connection>
<developerConnection>scm:jazz:username;password@https://jtsrv.him:9091/jazz:My Repository Workspaces/Log-MainStream</developerConnection>
```

Problem : I am not able to connect with repository workspace, Can someone help me for correcting this scm connection url?

```
My RTC repository hirarchy is below:

My Repository Workspaces

-Log-MainStream

    Below error I am getting when run the mvn scm:status command

[ERROR] Error: Problem running 'status':
Either specify repository or a directory to run on, or run in a shared directory    
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] Error code for Jazz SCM status command - 5
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Problem running 'status':
Either specify repository or a directory to run on, or run in a shared directory

I am using below maven release plugin       
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-jazz</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.2</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the scm section of the pom.xml file could look like:

```
<scm>
    <url>https://rtc:9444/jazz:GPDBBuildWorkspace</url>
    <connection>scm:jazz:https://rtc:9444/jazz:GPDBBuildWorkspace</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:jazz:https://rtc:9444/jazz:GPDBBuildWorkspace</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

the username and password are not in the pom.xml, they must be obtained from the user's settings.xml file. This is a sample of what the server section of the settings.xml file could look like:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>rtc:9444</id>
    <username>build</username>
    <password>build</password>
  </server>
```

I think it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply You have used here repository as GPDBBuildWorkspace
but in my case like standard RTC structure
My Repository Workspace contains all the repository created by user
so my main Question is how we can used it in scm connection url

Comment: in the maven documentation i look at the exemple :

scm:jazz:[username[;password]@]http[s]://server_name[:port]/jazzPath:repositoryWorkspace

scm:jazz:username;password@https://server.name:9443/jazz:Chris's Repository Workspace

in your exemple you have : My Repository Workspaces/Log-MainStream
i don't understand why you use this sentence in scm connection ?!!

Comment: Actually that is my question, I have used here "My Repository Workspaces/Log-MainStream" because in scm connection url, it need repositoy workspace and i have Log-MainStream is my repository WS.

But because of this I am not able to connect to RTC. so What should be the ideal way to connect to RTC ? How to form correct URL here?

Comment: This GPDBBuildWorkspace is belong to build user right?

But here Log-MainStream WS is my WS

Comment: I am not able to connect to scm using external username and password 

I tried it using below: 

Settings.xml 

<server> 
   <id>https://jtsrv:9094</id> 
   <username>****</username> 
   <password>****</password> 
  </server> 


POM.xml 

<scm> 
     <connection>scm:jazz:https://jtsrv:9094/jazz:/RepoWorkspace</connection> 
  <developerConnection>scm:jazz:https://jtsrv:9094/jazz:/RepoWorkspace</developerConnection> 
  <url>scm:jazz:https://jtsrv:9094/jazz:/RepoWorkspace</url>   
 </scm>

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

Workspace repository should always be shared in the RTC.
If it is disconnected from RTC repository Workspace then it will throw error while connecting to RTC through maven scm plugin

Comment: Here when I set the username and password in settings.xml, it is not picking up when running mvn scm:status command

Getting following error:
CRJAZ0124I Invalid username or password